# Application Security's Certification

Tags: security, certificate

In our campany we are developing a Web Applications (Finance, Stock...)

Our customers are very attentive in all aspects of security.

Is there organizations that analyzes security and gives in the end certificates recognized worldwide?

NB: Our applications are developed with PHP / MySQL.
N.B: Sorry for my bad English and I hope that I'm not writing in a wrong category.

Answer (score 0):

there are well known companies such as siemens which provide security assessement services. you could contact them.they may even be in your country.you could check this link it could help: http://www.usa.siemens.com/answers/en/#2288770-2289070